# Extracting text after a phrase and in between spaces from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a CSV with some data I am bringing into a pandas dataframe. One of the columns contains data that is a long text field like this:

"QB Aaron Rodgers RB Josh Jacobs FLEX Davante Adams"

I want to extract out the player name after FLEX for each row within this dataframe. I am a novice with regex in general and especially with lookahead and lookbehinds but was able to use this piece of code to get the text directly **before** the term FLEX

```
df.Lineup.str.extract('(\w+(?=\s+FLEX\s))')
```

However, I am trying to get the next **two words** (the full name) **after** the term FLEX. Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly?

For additional clarity, in the example above the current code results in me getting "Jacobs" back but I want "Davante Adams"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the match *Jacobs* as the pattern `(\w+(?=\s+FLEX\s))` matches 1+ word characters asserting what is directly to the right is whitespace chars followed by FLEX.

Instead, you can use a pattern with a capture group to match 2 words after FLEX:

```
\bFLEX\s+(\w+\s+\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rpmYr6/1)

Or a broader match:

```
\bFLEX\s+(\S+\s+\S+)
```

- `\bFLEX` A word boundary, match `FLEX`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\S+\s+\S+)` Capture **group 1** match 1+ non whitespace chars, 1+ whitespace chars and again 1+ non whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhkpJJ/1).

```
import pandas as pd

strings = ['QB Aaron Rodgers RB Josh Jacobs FLEX Davante Adams']
df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["Lineup"])
df['Lineup'] = df["Lineup"].str.extract(r'\bFLEX\s+(\S+\s+\S+)')
print(df)
```

Output

```
          Lineup
0  Davante Adams
```

---

If you want to match 2 or more words, you could use a repeating non capture group:

```
\bFLEX\s+(\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks! You could use replace like this `df['Lineup'] = df["Lineup"].str.replace(r'^.*?\bFLEX\s+(\w+\s+\w+).*', r'\1')`